# Display location of max value in data frame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I made a code that goes through a folder of csv files that look like this: [image]
The code finds the max values of 4 different ranges within the files and displays it. I would like to pull the value from the x-axis row that is associated with where the max was found so I know where the highest temperature occurred within a given range.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('C:/Users/dshar/Documents/Heating Trials OF/*.csv'):
    df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    df1=df.iloc[:, 100:175]
    df2=df.iloc[:, 175:250]
    df3=df.iloc[:, 250:350]
    df4=df.iloc[:, 350:420]
    max1=df1.max().max()
    max2=df2.max().max()
    max3=df3.max().max()
    max4=df4.max().max()
    taree=df.loc[0][1]
    print(taree)
    if str(taree)=='nan':
        xval1=df1.idxmax(axis=1).idxmax()
        xval2=df2.idxmax(axis=1).idxmax()
        xval3=df3.idxmax(axis=1).idxmax()
        xval4=df4.idxmax(axis=1).idxmax()
        valtype=df.loc[2][2]
        results=str(filename)+': measurement='+str(valtype)+'; max1= '+str(max1)+' at ' +str(xval1)+'; max2= '+str(max2)+' at ' +str(xval2)+'; max3= '+str(max3)+' at ' +str(xval3)+'; max4= '+str(max4)+' at ' +str(xval4)+'\n'
    else:
        xval1=df1.idxmax().idxmax()
        xval2=df2.idxmax().idxmax()
        xval3=df3.idxmax().idxmax()
        xval4=df4.idxmax().idxmax()
        valtype=df.loc[2][2]
        results=str(filename)+': measurement='+str(valtype)+'; max1= '+str(max1)+' at ' +str(xval1)+'; max2= '+str(max2)+' at ' +str(xval2)+'; max3= '+str(max3)+' at ' +str(xval3)+'; max4= '+str(max4)+' at ' +str(xval4)+'\n'

    print(results)
    
print('done')
```

from the code I'm currently recieving the following results and error:

measurement

C:/Users/dshar/Documents/Heating Trials OF\Heating Trial 1 (4kW 153V 60Hz 2PW)_2022-06-24_16-56-06_ch1_full.csv: measurement=temperature; max1= 145.5 at 0.5844; max2= 136.0 at 0.9744; max3= 144.1 at 1.3644; max4= 29.2 at 2.0612

nan

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/dshar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/dataProcessing2.py", line 17, in 
xval1=df1.idxmax(axis=1).idxmax()
File "C:\Users\dshar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2404, in idxmax
i = self.argmax(axis, skipna, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\dshar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 657, in argmax
return nanops.nanargmax(  # type: ignore[return-value]
File "C:\Users\dshar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 88, in _f
raise TypeError(
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: can you please share first few lines of your dataframe ? `df.loc[:20].to_dict()` . it would help people to reproduce the scenario

Comment: `idxmax` is usually the way to do that.  Though, looks like you are already aware of that.  if `x-axis` is the index then you would have your answer.  If not then you could use the index value returned by `idxmax` to lookup the `x-axis` value.

Comment: The issue is that with some files the x-axis becomes the second row value due to the software listing the tare for the sensors above it. Using `xval1=df1.idxmax().idxmax()` works but only as long as the x-axis values are in the first row. I'm currently trying to make an if else statement but can't figure out how to set `xval1=df1.idxmax().idxmax()` to take the 2nd row of the dataframe.